# Indy HTTP server on Linux returns only last character of response text

Tags: linux, delphi, http, freepascal, indy10

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Indy 10.5.9 rev 4885, Lazarus 1.0.4 / FPC 2.6.0.

With my simple TIdHTTPServer test program, the web browser only displays the last character ('!') instead of the of the complete response which should be 'Hello world!'.

I can see that in function `ToBytes` (line 6059 in IdGlobal.pas) the text in the passed AValue parameter is still correct, ASrcEncoding is an TIdASCIIEncoding and ADestEncoding is 'ISO-8559-1'. After executing line 6061 (LBytes := TIdTextEncoding.Convert(ASrcEncoding, ADestEncoding, LBytes);) the LBytes array contains #33 followed by zeroes.

My example project:

```
program MyHTTPServer;

uses
  cthreads,
  IdHTTPServer, IdCustomHTTPServer, IdContext, IdSocketHandle, IdGlobal,
  SysUtils;

type
  TMyServer = class (TIdHTTPServer)
  public
    procedure InitComponent; override;
    procedure OnGet(AContext: TIdContext;
    ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
  end;

procedure Demo;
var
  Server: TMyServer;
begin
  Server := TMyServer.Create(nil);
  try
    Server.Active := True;
    WriteLn('Hit any key to terminate.');
    ReadLn;
  finally
    Server.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyServer.InitComponent;
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  inherited;

  OnCommandGet := OnGet;

  Bindings.Clear;
  Binding := Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := '127.0.0.1';
  Binding.Port := 8080;
  Binding.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
end;

procedure TMyServer.OnGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin    
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Hello world!';
end;

begin
  IdGlobal.GIdIconvUseTransliteration := True;

  Demo;
end.
```

Comment: Since you are debugging into Indy's code, can you look inside `TIdTextEncoding.GetChars()` and `TIdTextEncoding.GetBytes()` and see which one is actually at fault?  I wrote `TIdTextEncoding` and getting the iconv library working in it has been a PITA. Partly because I don't have a Linux system myself, and partly because Indy does not have cross-platform access to `errno` yet to handle iconv errors correctly.

Comment: The `ASource.GetChars(ABytes)` call in IdGlobal.pas line 1779 returns the correct bytes. GetBytes calls GetBytes(@AChars[ACharIndex], ACharCount, @VBytes[AByteIndex], Len) in line 1965. I will try to debug into GetBytes and come back if I find more

Comment: I found that the iconv outbuf parameter always points to the first position of the result buffer (parameter `Bytes: PBytes`). If I place the line `LBytesPtr := PAnsiChar(Bytes);` up before the conversion loop it works.

Comment: Good catch. I will post an official fix shortly.

Comment: I have checked in a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in SVN trunk revision 4889.